# canvas fillText and fillRec not rendering

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Anyone know HTML5 with Javascript? Canvas specifically. I'm having trouble rendering the canvas on codepen, it doesn't work (doesn't show up the rectangle neither the text on the purple canvas when clicked on the purple button) but everything seems to be fine on my code. My codepen is: https://codepen.io/elohim-filipe-figueiras-do-campo/pen/QWwJwZX

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>"Event Driven Programming"</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ibarra+Real+Nova|Six+Caps&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

      <h1>Event Driven Programming</h1>
    <canvas id="First" class="FirstSection" class="_1st">

    </canvas>
    <canvas id="Second" class="SecondSection" class="_2nd">

    </canvas>
    <input type="button" value="Change Color" id="test" onclick="changeColor()">

    <input type="button" value="purple" onclick="doPurple()">
    <input type="button" value="red" onclick="doRed()">

  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
h1{
  border-bottom: 10px solid #FF0000;
  text-align: center;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  font-family: 'Six Caps', sans-serif;
  font-size: 60px;
}
body{
  padding: 10px;

}
#First{
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 10px solid #000000;
  font-family:'Ibarra Real Nova', serif;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;

}
#Second{
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border: 10px solid #000000;
  font-family: 'Ibarra Real Nova', serif;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.FirstSection{
  background-color: darkblue;
}
.SecondSection{
  background-color: darkgreen;
}
._1st{
  background-color: #FFCC00;
}
._2nd{
  background-color: #ff00ff;
}

canvas{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function changeColor(){
  var first =               document.getElementById("First");
  var second = document.getElementById("Second");
  first.className = "_1st";
  second.className = "_2nd";
}
function doPurple(){
  var first = document.getElementById("First");
  first.style.backgroundColor = "purple";
  var ctx = first.getContext("2d");
  ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
  ctx.fillRect = (10,10,100,100);

  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.font = "10px sans";
  ctx.fillText = ("Hello", 110,110);

}

function doRed(){
  document.getElementById("Second").style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

Comment: fillText and fillRect are functions. `ctx.fillRect = (10,10,100,100);` should be `ctx.fillRect(10,10,100,100);` same for the `fillText`